# What is the proper way to return something like a flat_hash_map that can be used by multiple functions?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

For instance, let's say we create the flat_hash_map

```
flat_hash_map<string, string> mapping = {
  "K1", "V1",
  "K2", "V2",
};
```

To return it from a function with there are a few options

A. Just return as value

```
flat_hash_map<string, string> GetMapping() {
 ..
 return mapping;
}
```

B. Return unique_ptr

```
unique_ptr<flat_hash_map<string, string>> GetMapping() {
 ...
 return make_unique<flat_hash_map<string, string>>(mapping);
}
```

Questions:

1. Is there any reason to use (B) over (A) assuming the object will only be used in one function?
2. If the mapping is intended to be passed around a lot, which option is preferred? Are there any good practices to remember to do (for instance cleaning up)?
3. Is there a need to clean up this object in any other scenario?

Comment: Normally, containers should be implemented to be fast to move. So there is usually not really any advantage to having a `unique_ptr` to a container. The notable exception being `std::array`.

Comment: If the map outlives the function (ie. is not created by/in the function), you may also want to return it by reference

Comment: If you are using C++17 or later and all branches in `GetMapping()` lead to the return of the created `flat_hash_map`, just return it _by-value_ and [RVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) kicks in.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes: It is intended to be created by the function but live longer. I'm not sure who should own or delete it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Makes sense, what is the best way without RVO? Is it using a smart pointer? If so, what is the correct way to create the smart pointer or clean up later?

Comment: Which C++ version are you using? C++11 and C++14 was allowed to do copy elision so most (perhaps all) implementations did that (which then became mandatory in C++17 as RVO). If your implementation does not support that, I'd still return _by-value_. Your `flat_hash_map` is most probably _movable_ so it'll still be very cheap. A `unique_ptr` may be a tiny bit cheaper in those cases but then you've optimized the program for legacy implementations.